# OpAmp Compensation - Poles and Zeros

Tags: operational-amplifier

I would be very happy if anyone can help me find answers regarding to questions below:

I provided a picture below from TI. I know that impedance of Cn is changing in accordance with the frequency thus it affects the \$\frac{1}{β}\$. On the other hand, Cn is short at high frequencies and open at low frequencies.

My questions are regarding to the poles and zeros as given at the lower left corner. At some specific frequency the impedance of the Cn will be equal to Rn  and RI.However,

1. how do they know that pair of Cn and Rn creates a pole and pair of Cn and RI creates zero at \$\frac{1}{β}\$ curve by directly looking at the graph ?
2. Is there any statement that directly tells us that ? for example if R and C are in series creates pole or zero or if they are in paralel creates poles or zero? because ı saw many videos that directly tells the whether they are poles or zeros.

[image]

Informations regarding to the source of picture :
Link : https://picture.iczhiku.com/resource/eetop/SHKlYzWoRirirbNX.pdf
Name of the Document: Operational Amplifier Stability - Loop-Stability Key Tricks and Rules of Thumb
Author: Tim Green from TI

Comment: Mhan - Hi, The [site rule](/help/referencing) says that if a post copies or adapts content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) from elsewhere, that content must be correctly referenced. Thanks for saying the image source was TI. However as a minimum, for online material, the source webpage / PDF / video etc. should be named (just saying TI isn't enough) *and its link provided*. Therefore please [edit] your question to include the name / title of the original source webpage / PDF / video *and its link* for that image (and please remember it's your responsibility to do that in future). Thanks

Comment: @SamGibson - Hello Sir, okay ı will follow the rules regarding to the references and sources. Since ı am new here, i didnt know the rules exactly and deeply. I apologize for that. Thank you. Best regards.

Comment: If you don't understand the circuit, you can try to write and solve its transfer function. It gives you direct answer.

Answer (score 5):

The fast analytical techniques or FACTs can shed some light on this circuit and let you compute the pole-zero position quite quickly. First off, open the capacitor to compute the gain at dc, for \$s=0\$. This is a non-inverting configuration so the gain is \$H_0=\frac{R_f}{R_i}+1\$.

Then, we have a pole in this circuit but what is the natural time constant? Set the excitation to 0 V (short the \$V_{in}\$ source) and "look" through the capacitor terminals that you have temporarily disconnected. Since you have a virtual ground at the (-) pin, the resistance \$R\$ you see is simply \$R_n\$ because \$R_i\$ is grounded in one side and has the 0-V virtual ground on the other side so its off the picture. The pole is the inverse of the time constant: \$\omega_p=\frac{1}{R_nC_n}\$

For the zero, you can also determine its position by inspection, at least to understand how it manifests itself. When the input stimulus is tuned at the zero angular frequency \$\omega_z\$, the output is *nulled*, there is 0 V in ac. What condition, in this circuit would authorize this condition? Well, if the gain is \$H(s)=\frac{R_f}{Z_i(s)}+1\$, then if \$\frac{R_f}{Z_i(s)}=-1\$ then you have a null on the output. Solve for \$s_z\$ in that condition and you have your zero which is slightly complicated as it depends on \$R_f\$ as well:

[image]

As you can see, the zero expression is not the one you gave in your picture. The two expressions, brute-force and the *low-entropy* version are rigorously equal. You can learn about the FACTs with my [APEC 2016](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202016.pdf) seminar.

A quick SIMetrix simulation compares the SPICE ac answer and the transfer function I derived: they are identical.

[image]

Comment: Hello Sir, thanks for your explanation but ı have question. I solved the transfer function as classic way so ı  found the same poles and zeros with your way as you provided in the image. Zero is indicated as 1/2*pi*RI*CN in my picture, this is totaly wrong right ? If so why do they provide such a wrong information ? because ı watch many videos in which peoples are doing the same thing. @Verbal Kint

Comment: @Mhan, hello, I suspect some approximation can be made if resistor \$R_i\$ is way smaller than the other ones. So rather than saying \$\omega_z=\$ it should say \$\omega_z \approx\$.

Comment: Hello Sir, what if we have inverting opamp, in that case instead of the ground at the end of the feedback we will have input. Does same rules applies again by solving either your way or general way ? How should ı think if we have input in the feedback from the ground side ? @Verbal Kint

Comment: @Mhan, hello, of course, if you have an inverting amplifier, then the gain is \$H(s)=-\frac{R_f}{Z_i(s)}\$ and you can use either method to obtain the transfer function. If you use FACTs, the zero is obtained when \$Z_i(s)\$ goes infinite for \$s=s_z\$, implying a zero located at \$\omega_z=\frac{1}{C_1(R_i+R_n)}\$, which is the pole of \$Z_i(s)\$.

Comment: Hello sir, another question is poles creates -90 degree , zero creates +90 degree. But in your graph poles has -80 degree and zero has arond +80 degree ? why dont we have -90 and +90 degree ? and sometimes  other graphs has different phase other than -90 and +90 for poles and zeros, why is this sir ? @Verbal Kint

Comment: Please have a look at my [APEC 2010](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202010.pdf) seminar, slide 39 where it shows how having first a zero starts by *boosting* the phase towards 90° but then the pole kicks in and brings the phase back to 0° by contributing a phase *lag*. If the zero and the pole are far from each other, then yes, the phase boost peaks to 90° but if they come closer, you reduce the bump (like the 80° in the graph) down to 0° if they are coincident.

Answer (score 3):

I drew a schematic with just the feedback network. "V" is an AC voltage source for simulation (corresponding to the opamp's output), and "FB" is the output of this feedback network.

At low frequency, the cap can be considered open circuit, so we get the middle schematic: a voltage divider of ratio RI/(RI+RF).

At high enough frequency, the cap can be considered a short circuit, so we get the schematic on the right: the bottom resistor in the voltage divider is the parallel combination of RI and RN, let's call it RP = 1/(1/RI+1/RN). The ratio of this voltage divider is Rp/(Rp+RF) and it is lower than the previous one.

[image]

Between the two frequency extremes there will be a transition.

[image]

About poles and zeros:

The pole is due to the cap being on the low side of the voltage divider. As frequency increases, its impedance decreases, and at this position in the voltage divider this reduces the output signal and adds 90° phase lag. It's a pole.

If the cap was on the high side of the voltage divider, it would be the opposite: as frequency increases, its impedance decreases, which means the output signal increases and there is still 90° phase shift but it's the opposite polarity, leading instead of lagging. It would be a zero.

The pole created by CN occurs at a frequency where the impedance of (CN in series with RN) is equal to the impedance of RI. Let's step CN with values 1nF, 10nF, 100nF: the pole (black arrow) moves in frequency accordingly.

[image]

Then after the pole, gain falls at -20dB/decade, until the impedance of RN becomes equal to that of CN. At this point, as frequency increases, the impedance of CN further diminishes but the impedance of the branch is dominated by RN, so the gain flattens and phase shift returns to zero. This means RN introduces a zero (green arrow) which counters CN's pole.

Let's step RN through various values. Intuitively, if RN is very high, much higher than RI, then the branch with RN becomes irrelevant. On the other hand, if RN is very low, let's say zero ohms, then the gain no longer flattens at high frequency.

[image]

> 2. Is there any statement that directly tells us that ? for example if R and C are in series creates pole or zero or if they are in paralel creates poles or zero? because ı saw many videos that directly tells the whether they are poles or zeros.

It depends on the circuit. All the cap does is change impedance versus frequency. What that does to the response of the whole circuit (add a pole, a zero...) depends on how it's wired. So you have to understand the circuit and (for example) draw a rough plot of its frequency response and check what components add poles (gain going down -20dB/decade + 90° phase lag) and zeros (gain going up -20dB/decade + 90° phase lead).

For example if we swap the top part and bottom part of the voltage divider: now CN adds a zero, and RN adds a pole.

[image]

Comment: Hello Sir, thanks for your clear explanation but ı have question.1) I solved the transfer function so ı found [(RI+RF)/RI]x [1+sC(RN*RI+RN*RF+RF*RI)/ (1+sCRN)] . As you can see the pole of fp= 1/(2*pi*RN*CN) mathces with the picture. But zero, fz, is not matching with what is given in the picture that ı provided. Do you have any suggection for that ? 2) what come to my mind is that what if we have inverting opamp, in that case instead of the ground of the feedback will have input? so in that case how can ı think of Cn branch is at low or high side ? @bobflux

Comment: Hello sir, poles creates -90 degree , zero creates +90 degree. But in your first graph poles has -60 degree and in your last graph zero has arond +48 degree ? why dont we have -90 and +90 degree ? @bobflux

Comment: Transition from 0 to +/-90 takes about one frequency decade. If the pole and zero are close together in frequency, their phase shifts add (with opposite signs) so they cancel, and there isn't enough "space" in frequency between them for the phase shift to reach 90.